# Pandas - How best to combing dataframes based on specific column values

Tags: pandas

I have my main data frame (df) with the six columns defined in 'column_main'.

The needed data comes from two much larger df's.  Let's call them df1 and df2.

Plus df1 & df2 do not have the same columns labels.  But they both include the required df columns.

The df just has the few pieces that are needed from each for the two bigger ones. And by bigger, I mean many times the columns.

Since it is all going into a DB I want to get rid of all the unwanted columns.

How do I combine/merge/join/mask the needed data from the large data frames into the main (smaller) data frame?  or maybe drop the columns not covered by 'columns_main'.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = columns_main)
```

The other two df's are coming from excel workbooks with a lot of unwanted trash.

```
wb = load_workbook(filename = filename )

ws = wb[_sheets[0]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(ws.values)

ws = wb[_sheets[1]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(ws.values)
```

How can I do without some sort of crazy looping?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you create some data samples?

Comment: yes, column_main is the main dataframe.  the worksheets might have 30 columns.

Comment: So need `df1[df['column_main']]` and `df2[df['column_main']]` ?

Comment: yes, that looks like it might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select another DataFrames by subset:

```
df1[df['column_main']]
df2[df['column_main']]
```

If possible some columns not match use [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html):

```
cols = df['column_main']

df1[df1.columns.intersection(cols)]
df2[df2.columns.intersection(cols)]
```

Comment: not happening but i think it is in the data.  very inconsistant output.  Example:  a3. holder vs a3.holder.  note the space after the period for the first one.  I have to figure out how to remove that formatting before it will fit.

Comment: so how long before you get to 1M???  you are amazing.

Comment: @diogenes - hmm, can you ad soem data sample to question?

Comment: ok, the excel files have differnt formatting

Comment: 'a2.holder name', 'a3.holder state of domicile', 'b1. investment objective'

Comment: throughout some names have a space after the period and others do not.

Comment: would it be better to rename columns in pandas or openpyxl?  i need to remove the ". " and replace with "."

Comment: @diogenes - Need match values before dot? `a2, a3, b1` ?

Comment: looking at several of their exel files - looks like the a2, b3, b1 might work. some of their column heading are very long!

Comment: is it possible to drop everything starting at the period in the column names?

Comment: E.g. `df1 = df1.rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('.')[0])` should working